# Optimizing Spark Jobs

Tags: sql, apache-spark, optimization, hive

I have a spark job that reads and transforms data from hive. The data is partitioned by date and each partition is about 2gb of data. The job in best case is run on per day on worst case is for a month 28/29/30/31 days period

The transformation has some transformers that cause shuffling groupby and distinct. I have a 10 cluster node with a total 1.5TB of memory and 480 cores. when running the job it takes forever and then terminates.

SQL Transformation

```
With dbsase as (

          SELECT 
              user_id,
              month,
              a,
              b,
              c,
              d,
              e,
              f,
              ....,
              min(day) min_day
            from db.db
            GROUP BY 
              user_id,
              month,
              a,
              b,
              c,
              d,
              e,
              f,
              ....


)
          SELECT 
            distinct min_day,
              a,
              b,
              c,
              d,
              e,
              f,
              ....

            COUNT(user_id) OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
            trunc(to_date(min_day), "MM"),
              a,
              b,
              c,
              d,
              e,
              f,
              ....

            ORDER BY min_day
            ) cumulative_active_users
            
          FROM dbsase
          ORDER BY 1
```

I tried running the job both on yarn and local[*] I have tried a multitude of increasing and decreasing the

- driver memory
- executor memory
- num of executors

but the job is still very slow please any idea on what I am missing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems are-

1. Since your SQL is using whole table its not using partition pruning. See if you can run for a particular month.
2. `distinct` over many columns is a memory intensive operation and you should avoid it at all costs or build some other solution to do it.
3. `Order by 1` - To load data automatically, this is useless. see that if you can avoid it.
4. All columns cant be key columns and shouldn't be used in comparison. find a key column and use it in window function.

Now, in case you cant really tune it, you can do a two step approach -

step 1 - use your main SQL and create a non distinct table.

```
With dbsase as (

          SELECT  col1, col2, min(day) min_day
            from db.db
            GROUP BY col1,col2
)
          SELECT 
            min_day, col1, col2,
            COUNT(user_id) OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
            trunc(to_date(min_day), "MM"),col1, col2,
            ORDER BY min_day
            ) cumulative_active_users
            
          FROM dbsase
```

step 2 - Then use above stage table and get distinct from that table and select/insert into final table.

Comment: Thanks for this I later applied some of your suggestions now it runs in 30 min still a bit long but acceptable for now. Thanks again